# Touching a file with SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

In ant I used to "touch" a file changing its timestamp for the web application to be reloaded. Now I'm working with SBT(in Eclipse) and need to do the same. Is there an equivalent in SBT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

- [`sbt.IO.touch`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-zero-thirteen/blob/0.13/util/io/src/main/scala/sbt/IO.scala#L182-L201) in sbt 0.13, and
- [`sbt.io.IO.touch`](https://github.com/sbt/io/blob/1.0/io/src/main/scala/sbt/io/IO.scala#L153-L172) in sbt 1.0 milestones.

The API is the same in both case, `object IO` has just been moved in 1.0.

Writing a task to touch the file should be easy:

```
lazy val touch = taskKey[Unit]("Touch my file")

touch := {
  IO.touch(file("foo"))
}
```